# Select rows with reference to other rows in same table

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table `foo` with the following structure:

```
| id | docId  | content | parentId |
|----|--------|---------|----------|
| 1  | 19     | ...     | NULL     |
| 2  | 20     | ...     | NULL     |
| 3  | 20     | ...     | NULL     |
| 4  | NULL   | ...     | 3        |
| 5  | 20     | ...     | NULL     |
| 6  | NULL   | ...     | 5        |
| 7  | 21     | ...     | NULL     |
| 8  | NULL   | ...     | 7        |
| 9  | NULL   | ...     | 7        |
```

I want to select everything with `docId = 20`, or with a parentId which corresponds to a row with `docId = 20`.

I thought I'd get there using a LEFT JOIN but no luck:

```
SELECT * FROM foo a
LEFT JOIN foo b ON b.id = a.parentId
WHERE a.docId = 20
```

This returns all the rows where `docId = 20` but not the ones where `docId = NULL` and a parentId is a row with docId 20.

Comment: You need to include `OR b.parentId = 20` in your WHERE clause.

Comment: Thanks, but b.parentId refers to another row's `id` and not another rows `docId`.

Comment: Correcting @MadMarc - you need to include `OR a.parentId = 20`

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using a subquery instead of a JOIN:

```
SELECT * FROM foo
WHERE parentId IN (SELECT id FROM foo WHERE docId = 20)
OR docId = 20
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try a union

```
SELECT * FROM foo a
LEFT JOIN foo b ON b.id = a.parentId
WHERE a.docId = 20    
UNION 
SELECT * FROM foo
WHERE docId = 20
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have mistake in your join rule, 
I believe you have to use `a.id = b.parentId` not `b.id = a.parentId`, like:

```
SELECT * FROM foo a
LEFT JOIN foo b ON a.id = b.parentId
WHERE a.docId = 20
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM foo
    WHERE docId = 20
    UNION
    SELECT b.* 
    FROM foo a
    JOIN foo b ON a.id = b.parentId
    WHERE a.docId = 20
```

answers your question about parents, if you want grandparents and other ancestors, you may want to consider recursive CTEs.